# HTML Rollover w/o background-image tag

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, rollover

I'm using a CMS that restricts tags so I can't use the background-image tag to create a image rollover link.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of backwards CMS would disallow CSS....

Comment: If we knew what you were trying to achieve it would help. What kind of 'rollover link'?

Comment: So if you can't use `background-image` in CSS what **can** you use?

Comment: Like @Paulie_D asked, what can you use? If you can ONLY use text then you are SOL.

Comment: Just a simple img replacement rollover, I tried using

`<a title="See Uniforms" target="_self" href="../cat-33-1-64/uniforms.htm"><img alt="See Uniforms" src="Poloroid_Uniforms.png" onmouseout="this.src'Poloroid_Uniforms.png'" onmouseover="this.src='Poloroid_Uniforms_hov.png'"  /></a>`

But it rearranges the code alphabetically, disabling this.  I'm trying to figure out a way to possibly use opacity and :hover

Comment: "But it rearranges the code alphabetically"...WHAT!?

Comment: I mean in theory you could have a couple of absolutely positioned divs containing images **inside** the anchor link but that sounds like a shipload of work to achieve something the CMS is **clearly** designed to sop you doing

Comment: @Newcombe So you can't edit the CSS at all?